# My login code doesnt work the first time? The second time it does?

Tags: php, session

i'm having a bit of a problem with my login code, when i try to login it doesnt work the first time. I dont know what im doing wrong but the first time it will always give me the error, here's the code (the comments are in dutch):

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            //Maakt de variables korter, en beschermt ze tegen sql injectie d.m.v. real_escape
            $gb = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

            //Deze maakt de wachtwoord en salt 1 Dat zorgt ervoor als je database
            //ooit wordt gehackt, ze niet je klanten hun wachtwoord hebben.
            $ww1 = $password.$salt;

            //Deze encrypt het nieuwe wachtwoord, dus bijv stel het wachtwoord is lol123 en je salt is abc123
            //dan is het wachtwoord lol123abc123
            $ww = sha1($ww1);

            //Vergeet niet de tablenaam medewerkers aan te passen naar jou shit.
             //Dit is de query
            $select_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$gb' AND password='$ww'";

            //Deze zin runned de query daadwerkelijk
            $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);

            //Deze kijkt hoeveel ROWS er terugzijn gekomen, als het meer dan 1 is klopt het dus.
            $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
                if($check_user>0){
                    session_start();
                        $_SESSION['username'] = "$gb";
                            echo "<script>{location.href = 'home.php'; };</script>";
                    }else {
                        echo "<p> Gegevens kloppen <b>niet!</b></p>";
                 }
            }
        ?>
```

This is the code for the login page^.

This is the code for the home page where it will go to after logging in:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if(strlen($username) < 1){
    die('Error');
}
?>
```

I really dont know whats wrong

Comment: You're doing several things wrong... Using `escape_string` instead of prepared queries, using `sha1` instead of `password_hash`/`password_verify` and so on.

Comment: you should start the session in the first file before anything is happening or meant to happen. Also checking if the session is set.

Comment: but does this effect the 2 times login thing?

Comment: That was it, i didnt start the session in the login. Thanks

Comment: @FluffyMe You're welcome, always `#ready to help`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments, you need to start the session first and placed on top before anything is happening or meant to happen.

So in your first file:

```
<?php 
session_start();

// rest of your code.
```

and checking if the session is set.

You should also use a prepared statement and `password_hash()`. Your present code isn't really all that safe to use, if you're going live or are live with this.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php (MySQLi_)
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php (PDO)
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

---

> *"but does this effect the 2 times login thing?"*

Yes it does matter. What happened here is that the session wasn't started as you loaded the login page because of its placement/location.

As soon as you reloaded it because the user was logged in and the session array was set/not empty, the session was started because it is included in that file, just further down.

- Its location is important.

You should also create a logout file and to destroy the session.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Otherwise, that may have adverse effects.

Comment: @FluffyMe Thanks :) *Cheers!*

Comment: @FluffyMe I made an additional edit to my answer, explaining what happened. It can be found under where I quoted you from comments: *"but does this effect the 2 times login thing?"* by reloading/refreshing it.